# How to add Persistent listener to Interactable events via code in editor?

Tags: mrtk

How to add Persistent listener to Interactable events via code in editor? I tried to use the methods from UnityEventTools AddPersistentListener to OnSelect and OnDeselect events in InteractableOnToggleReceiver class, but the event is only set on OnSelect, OnDeselect remains empty.

```
Interactable interact = button.GetComponent<Interactable>();
InteractableEvent ie = new InteractableEvent();
InteractableOnToggleReceiver tr = new InteractableOnToggleReceiver();
tr.Event = ie.Event;
ie.ReceiverType = tr.GetType();
UnityEventTools.AddBoolPersistentListener(tr.OnDeselect, item.gameObject.SetActive, false);
UnityEventTools.AddBoolPersistentListener(tr.OnSelect, item.gameObject.SetActive, true);
//
interact.InteractableEvents.Add(ie)
//or
//var lie = new List<InteractableEvent>();
//lie.Add(ie);
//interact.InteractableEvents = lie;
```

[image]